# Como guardo información en postgresql de una clase? error con StringVar() en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, tkinter

```py
import psycopg2
import sys
import pprint
import Base_de_datos

class Cliente:
    def __init__(self,id=None,nombre=None):
            self.id=id
            self.nombre=nombre
    def ingresar(self):
        self.ventanaIngresar=Tk()
        self.ventanaIngresar.geometry("570x400")
        self.ventanaIngresar.title("Cliente")
        Label(self.ventanaIngresar, text="Cliente",font=("Cambria",14)).place(x=5,y=0)
        Label(self.ventanaIngresar, text="Id: ",font=("Cambria",11)).place(x=0,y=30)
        Label(self.ventanaIngresar, text="Nombre: ",font=("Cambria",11)).place(x=0,y=60)

        Cliente.id=StringVar()
        Entry(self.ventanaIngresar, textvariable=Cliente.id).place(x=30,y=30)
        Cliente.nombre=StringVar()
        Entry(self.ventanaIngresar, textvariable=Cliente.nombre).place(x=65,y=60) 

        Button(self.ventanaIngresar,text="Guardar",font=("Cambria",11),
                   width=15,command=self.BD).place(x=420,y=5)


        self.ventanaIngresar.mainloop()
    def BD(self):
        """ID=Cliente.id.get()
        NOMBRE=Cliente.nombre.get()"""
        comando="INSERT INTO cliente(id, nombre) VALUES('"+id.get()+"','"+nombre.get()+ "')"
        conectar=Base_de_datos.BaseDeDatos()
        conectar.cursor.execute(comando)
```

este es mi Cliente.py y lo que quiero es que los datos que proporcione el usuario por un Entry se guarden en la base de datos, postgresql. y se conecta bien a la BD pero asi como lo tengo no sale nada en la BD

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en otras ocasiones como NONE.
si le quito los comentarios en esto:

```
"""ID=Cliente.id.get()
    NOMBRE=Cliente.nombre.get()"""
```

y en el comando asi:

```
comando="INSERT INTO cliente(id, nombre) VALUES('"+Cliente.id.set(ID)+"','"+Cliente.nombre.set(NOMBRE)+ "')"
```

me sale este error:

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly
```

y sé que tengo los atributos como NONE pero no puedo quitarlos porque en otro modulo llamo a esta clase asi:

```
cliente=Cliente.Cliente()
```

en fin, le he tratado de distintas formas, pero no me funciona, la verdad no tengo mucho conocimiento de python, apenas voy empezando y quisiera saber en que estoy mal y como podria solucionarlo. gracias

Comment: En lugar de concatenar strings con `+`, intenta crear una sola cadena con las funciones de formato de strings, como `%` o `str.format()`. Pero ten en cuenta que en la cadena resultante te saldrá "`None`" en ciertos lugares, que no sé si será válido para el comando SQL que intentas construir. Otra opción... ¿no sería mejor que un cliente sin nombre tenga una cadena vacía por nombre en lugar de `None`?

Comment: Otra cosa que he visto, en lugar de `id.get()` ¿no debería ser `self.id.get()`? (entiendo que quieres acceder al dato `id` del objeto)

Comment: Hola JLDiaz, gracias, pero ya intente de igual manera con % y str.format() pero sigue apareciendo solo la columna sin datos al igual que con self.id.get()           con respecto a lo de: ¿no sería mejor que un cliente...? no entendí muy bien jeje te refieres a que aparezca como NULL?

Comment: Creo que el "bug" de tu código era no usar `self` para acceder a los atributos. Resuelto eso, debería funcionar. Otra cosa es que permitas que el campo nombre esté vacío. En ese caso deberías tener claro qué debería ir a la base de datos para ese caso. Posiblemente una cadena vacía pueda funcionar, pero lo más correcto sería quizás NULL. Eso complica un poco las cosas pues en caso de que `self.id` o `self.nombre` sean `None`, lo que deberías volcar al comando SQL sería `NULL`, sin comillas, mientras que en caso de que sean distinto de `None` sería su valor, con comillas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambie tu código para que arme la query considerando  variables de instancia. Hasta el armado de la query funciona OK. Adicionalmente creo un objeto conexión (con mis datos, vos tendrás que usar los tuyos evidentemente para que puedas probar el código y ver que inserta el dato). Además adjunto capturas de pantalla de la definición de la tabla y de la inserción de registro ya que desconozco que hace Base_de_datos.BaseDeDatos()

```
class Cliente:
    def __init__(self, id=None, nombre=None):
        self.id = id
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.conexion = psycopg2.connect(
        "host='localhost' port='5433' dbname='Prueba123' user=postgres password=admin123")  

        self.conexion.autocommit = True
        self.cursor = self.conexion.cursor()

    def ingresar(self):
        self.ventanaIngresar = Tk()
        self.ventanaIngresar.geometry("570x400")
        self.ventanaIngresar.title("Cliente")
        Label(self.ventanaIngresar, text="Cliente", font=("Cambria", 14)).place(x=5, y=0)
        Label(self.ventanaIngresar, text="Id: ", font=("Cambria", 11)).place(x=0, y=30)
        Label(self.ventanaIngresar, text="Nombre: ", font=("Cambria", 11)).place(x=0, y=60)

        self.id = StringVar()
        Entry(self.ventanaIngresar, textvariable=self.id).place(x=30, y=30)
        self.nombre = StringVar()
        Entry(self.ventanaIngresar, textvariable=self.nombre).place(x=65, y=60)

        Button(self.ventanaIngresar, text="Guardar", font=("Cambria", 11),
               width=15, command=self.BD).place(x=420, y=5)

        self.ventanaIngresar.mainloop()

    def BD(self):
        """ID=Cliente.id.get()
        NOMBRE=Cliente.nombre.get()"""

        comando = "INSERT INTO cliente(id, nombre) VALUES('" + self.id.get() + "','" + self.nombre.get() + "')"
        print(comando)
        self.cursor.execute(comando)   
        #conectar = Base_de_datos.BaseDeDatos()
        #conectar.cursor.execute(comando)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adicionalmente, puse el codigo especificado por mi en esta respuesta en un archivo Cliente para luego utilizarlo como modulo desde un programa principal. De esta manera

```
import Cliente

if __name__=='__main__':
   c=Cliente.Cliente()
   c.ingresar()
```

El resultado es que funcionó OK también. Adjunto más capturas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Finalmente el último caso, para el cual se invoca desde otro formulario. Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
    import Cliente
    from Tkinter import *

    if __name__=='__main__':
       c=Cliente.Cliente()
       print(c)
       root=Tk()
       frame=Frame()
       frame.pack()
       b=Button(frame, text="Llamar", font=("Cambria", 11),
                   width=15, command=c.ingresar)
       b.pack()
       frame.mainloop()
```

Para este caso puntual ya que hay que utilizar un popup extra se tiene que usar en el modulo Cliente TopLevel (http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) en lugar de Tk, sino los datos quedan en blanco. El código que funciona para este caso es el siguiente del módulo Cliente. El único cambio es modificar self.ventanaIngresar = Tk() por self.ventanaIngresar = Toplevel()

```
from Tkinter import *
import psycopg2

class Cliente:
    def __init__(self, id=None, nombre=None):
        self.id = id
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.conexion = psycopg2.connect(
        "host='localhost' port='5433' dbname='Prueba123' user=postgres password=admin123")

        self.conexion.autocommit = True
        self.cursor = self.conexion.cursor()

    def ingresar(self):
        print(self.nombre)
        print(self.id)
        self.ventanaIngresar = Toplevel()
        self.ventanaIngresar.geometry("570x400")
        self.ventanaIngresar.title("Cliente")
        Label(self.ventanaIngresar, text="Cliente", font=("Cambria", 14)).place(x=5, y=0)
        Label(self.ventanaIngresar, text="Id: ", font=("Cambria", 11)).place(x=0, y=30)
        Label(self.ventanaIngresar, text="Nombre: ", font=("Cambria", 11)).place(x=0, y=60)

        self.id = StringVar()
        Entry(self.ventanaIngresar, textvariable=self.id).place(x=30, y=30)
        self.nombre = StringVar()
        Entry(self.ventanaIngresar, textvariable=self.nombre).place(x=65, y=60)

        Button(self.ventanaIngresar, text="Guardar", font=("Cambria", 11),
               width=15, command=self.BD).place(x=420, y=5)

        self.ventanaIngresar.mainloop()

    def BD(self):
        """ID=Cliente.id.get()
        NOMBRE=Cliente.nombre.get()"""
        print(self.id.get())
        comando = "INSERT INTO cliente(id, nombre) VALUES('" + self.id.get() + "','" + self.nombre.get() + "')"
        print(comando)
        self.cursor.execute(comando)
        #conectar = Base_de_datos.BaseDeDatos()
        #conectar.cursor.execute(comando)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y mientras tanto en la Base de datos....

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: De igual manera, aparece vacía la columna en postgresql, al parecer si toma bien los datos pero en postgresql no sale nada, solo crea la row. que podría ser?

Comment: Hola ahi edite la respuesta con el ejemplo funcionando hasta la inserción del registro. La conexión la creo por medio de  psycopg2.connect - Esto esta en el __init__. Como dije antes desconozco que hace Base_de_datos.BaseDeDatos(), pero como verás en mi ejemplo funciona OK. Ahora ya lo podes adaptar a tu caso particular.  Adjunto capturas de la definición de la tabla cliente y del registro añadido a la base de datos.

Comment: Gracias TheSupermax03 por responder, de hecho esta clase esta en un modulo diferente del principal, y llamo a esta clase Cliente desde el modulo principal.   cliente=Cliente.Cliente()  (el primero el objeto, el segundo el modulo y el tercero la clase) y en un botón llamo a la funcion ingresar command=cliente.ingresar........en fin, corri el programa no desde el modulo principal sino como tu lo hiciste y así sí me funciona bien y si se guardan los datos en postgresql, pero a la hora de correr el programa desde el modulo principal, me aparece vacío........qué es lo que podría hacer?

Comment: Hola, ahi puse mi codigo en un archivo llamado Cliente y lo llamo import como módulo (edite la respuesta y le puse mas capturas). Funciona Ok tambien. Si queres vemos como lo invocas, pero para eso necesitaría el codigo del programa llamador, en donde decis que pones el boton y lo llamas.

Comment: Le estuve dando vueltas al asunto y pude ver cual es el problema. Cuando uses otras ventanas hay que usar Toplevel() para instanciar. Volvi a editar la respuesta incluyendo esta opción. Al código que te especifique lo que hay que hacer es en  def ingresar(self) poner       self.ventanaIngresar = Toplevel() para el módulo Cliente y ahi funciona, ya lo cambie ya en la ultima actualización de mi respuesta. Fijate la parte final que empieza con "Finalmente el último caso, para el cual se invoca desde otro formulario. Tengo el siguiente codigo:"

Comment: rayos!! apenas voy aprendiendo Python y parece ser sencillo, aunque me atoro en problemas sencillos jaja gracias por la ayuda TheSupermax03 ya comenzaba a molestarme todo jaja pero voy entendiendo cada vez más todo, gracias!! :)